# Exim: send emails from different ips and hostnames on the same vps

Tags: smtp, centos7, exim

I have 2 ips on my server, I’m trying to set up 2 emails, one email sends from one ip, the other sends from the second ip. The first email is fine but I’m getting an error in mail-tester.com for the second email (ips are obviously dummy examples):

> Your IP address 1.1.1.2  is associated with the domain
> port25.domain.com. Nevertheless your message appears to be sent from
> port24.domain.com. You may want to change your pointer (PTR type) DNS
> record and the host name of your server to the same value. Here are
> the tested values for this check: IP: 1.1.1.2 HELO: port24.domain.com
> rDNS: port25.domain.com

My setup on my vps - 2 ip’s each has their own hostname rdns
port24.domain.com → 1.1.1.1 (ip1)
port25.domain.com → 1.1.1.2 (ip2)

I’ve set up 2 domains in vesta cp, domain1.com uses ip1, domain2.com uses ip2. DNS is correct.

I’ve created emails in roundcube. I’ve added the following to my exim conf:

> interface =
> ${lookup{$sender_address_domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/mailips}{$value}{}}
> helo_data = ${if exists
> {/etc/exim/mailhelo}{${lookup{$sender_address_domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/mailhelo}{$value}{$primary_hostname}}}{$primary_hostname}}

[(here is a link to a google doc with my exim config)](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1js3ALo-wiB5W15w-4q6dQoYPV6Fwg6mudVKCytujwh4/edit?usp=sharing)

I’ve added the following to my mailips and mailhelo file:

> mailips: domain1.com:1.1.1.1 domain2.com:1.1.1.2
>
> mailhelo: domain1.com: port24.domain.com domain2.com:
> port25.domain.com
> *: port24.domain.com

The previous error in mail-tester.com shows emails from domain2.com on 1.1.1.2 are coming from port24 when they should be coming from port25.

```
# telnet 1.1.1.2 587 
Trying 1.1.1.2... Connected to 1.1.1.2. Escape character is '^]'. 220 port24.domain.com ESMTP Exim 4.96 Sat, 08 Jul 2023 10:57:23 -1000
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Why two addresses of the same protocol in the first place? It is perfectly reasonable to have a single mail server, operated under the responsibility of a single business entity, to be handling mail for multiple domains. You may be trying to setup something complicated when the simpler solution is more appropriate.

Comment: I've got two teams of cold emailers and the idea was to keep the emails on their own ips. But I think you're right, keeping the email domains on the same ip is going to make things less complicated. I can't find any documentation about the solution otherwise.